# How can I copy thread data to an array before terminating the thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, struct, copying

I am attempting to copy thread data in C from within a method which references the thread's struct using a pointer to an array of the struct type.

I attempted to use the "&" symbol to get the struct data, but received a make error in doing so. I would like to copy the entire struct's data before the thread, which is of the struct's type, is terminated.

```
Person queue[300];
Person statsArray[300];
// the queue contains Person structs that have been given data already
//      within another method, prior to calling Leave().

typedef struct
{
struct timeval startChange;
struct timeval endChange;
struct timeval arrive;

int id;
int changingTime;
int storeTime;
int returning;
int numVisits;
int type;
int queuePos;
} Person;

void Leave(int queuePosition)
{
Person *aPerson = &queue[queuePosition];

statsArray[statsArrayIndex] = &aPerson;
statsArrayIndex++;
}
```

When compiling, I get the error of "incompatible types when assigning to type 'Person {aka struct }' from type 'Person ** {aka struct  **}'

Comment: In order to answer this question, it would be helpful to know how you are creating/handling the variable 'statsArrayIndex'. What is it based upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, the problematic line is:

```
statsArray[statsArrayIndex] = &aPerson;
```

where you assign a `Person**` to a `Person`. If you want to copy each struct element then you probably want:

```
statsArray[statsArrayIndex] = *aPerson;
```

Note that struct copying can be expensive for an array of large structs. Depending on your program, it may better/possible to re-design your program so as to not make a copy and just use a pointer to it (e.g., don't let the thread destroy `queue`).